# Loading images sometimes causes image to be loaded twice

Tags: javascript

I am working on an image preloading tool but I have come across a curious problem, whenever I supply multiple images to load, sometimes the first image gets processed twice.

I know it gets processed twice because at the end, when the loading is supposed to be complete, I log the array to the console and sometimes its:

`(2) [img] [img]`

(like its supposed to be) and if I keep refreshing I run sometimes run into:

```
(2) [img] [img]
(3) [img] [img]
```

This is the code below that produces that result. I don't understand why sometimes it returns the correct value and other times not. If you run the snippet below multiple times you will get the bad result one of those times.

It looks like `loadComplete()` is being hit twice which is confusing because there's a `return` after it so I don't see how it can be called multiple times.

```js
class Load {

  constructor() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.completed = [];
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.itemsCompleted = 0;
  }

  image(src) {
    return this.addToQueue(src);
  }

  addToQueue(src) {
    let item = {
      src: src,
      loaded: false
    };

    this.queue.push(item);
    this.totalItems++;

    return this;
  }

  addToCache() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.queue.length; i++) {

      let item = this.queue[i];

      if (item.loaded) {
        this.queue.splice(i, 1);
        i--;

        this.itemsCompleted++;

        break;

      }

      this.loadImage(item);

    }

    if (this.itemsCompleted == this.totalItems) {

      this.loadComplete();

      return;

    }
  }

  start() {
    this.addToCache();
  }

  loadImage(item) {
    item.data = new Image();

    item.data.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.completed.push(item.data);

      item.loaded = true;

      this.addToCache();
    });

    item.data.addEventListener('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    item.data.src = item.src;
    item.data.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  }

  loadComplete() {
    console.log(this.completed);
  }

}


let load = new Load();

load.image('https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg');

load.image('https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg');

load.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is your updating the complete in async so it does not count correctly here is an example of correction ( i am sorry it's a little messy but you can understand the idea ). Hope it helps

```js
class Load {

  constructor() {
    this.queue = [];
    this.completed = [];
    this.totalItems = 0;
    this.itemsCompleted = 0;
  }

  image(src) {
    return this.addToQueue(src);
  }

  addToQueue(src) {
    let item = {
      src: src,
      loaded: false
    };

    this.queue.push(item);
    this.totalItems++;

    return this;
  }

  addToCache() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.queue.length; i++) {

      let item = this.queue[i];

      if (item.loaded) {
        this.queue.splice(i, 1);
        i--;

        this.itemsCompleted++;

        break;

      }

      this.loadImage(item);

    }
    
  }
  loadCompleted(){
  if (this.completed.length == this.totalItems) {

      this.loadComplete();

      return;

    }
  }

  start() {
    this.addToCache();
  }

  loadImage(item) {
    item.data = new Image();

    item.data.addEventListener('load', () => {
      this.completed.push(item.data);
      this.loadCompleted();
    });
          item.loaded = true;

    item.data.addEventListener('error', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    item.data.src = item.src;
    item.data.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  }

  loadComplete() {
    console.log(this.completed);
  }

}


let load = new Load();

load.image('https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg');

load.image('https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg');

load.start();
```